# How can I assign active class to the current route link in ampersand.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ampersand, ampersand.js

I have these routes:

```
routes: {
   '': 'index',
   'lifestyle': 'lifestyle',
   'about': 'about'
},

index: function() {

},

lifestyle: function() {

},

about: function() { 

}
```

How can I determine which one is the active route so that I can assign 'active' class to the corresponding nav link?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to listen to the `route` event emitted by the router and assign your `active` class when it is fired. For your `routes` definition:

```
routes: {
   '': 'index',
   'lifestyle': 'lifestyle',
   'about': 'about'
}
```

You can listen like this to the `route` event:

```
router.on("route", function(page, ...arguments) {
  //here 'page' can be 'index', 'lifestyle' or 'about'.
  //then you can save the 'page' in a variable or assign your 'active' class right away
});
```

Also check out the [last paragraph of the documentation](https://ampersandjs.com/docs/#ampersand-router-routes)